# Java script on node js

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an html file to save data to txt file. I want this file to be written on the server. I hosted my application on node js and running with my IP. I want to save file on that server. when any user clicks on download me it should save in server path. Here is the code. I'm getting an uncaught exception.

```
<button onclick="Downloadme()">Downloadme</button>
<script>
    function downloadme(){ 
        var fs = require('fs'); 
        fs.writeFile('C:\\Users\\desktop\\filescopying\\myfile.txt', "Hey there!", function(err) { 
        if (err) { 
            return console.log(err); 
        } 
        console.log("The file was saved!");
        }); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side code and server-side code.  You need to run a `.js` file with node.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run node.js in the browser and write to the server.
You need to send the file you want to save to the nodejs server an then run the snippet you posted here with the received file itself.

Comment: Wow, that's complex...try this here:
https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/node-js-upload-file-to-server/